# accessing an attr_writer on a nested attribute asset from a file uploaded via form

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, file-upload, has-many-polymorphs

I have the following model structure

```
class Asset < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_writer :session_user_id
  ...
end

class Item < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :assets, :as => :assetable, :dependent => :destroy
  ...
end
```

and want to put the user_id in the value associated with an asset. I am having a problem associating a variable on an uploaded file. Here's the post'd data:

```
"assets_attributes"=>{"3"=>{"asset"=>#<ActionDispatch::Http::UploadedFile:0x007fd04dde17f8 @original_filename="nautugly.jpg",
@content_type="image/jpeg",
@headers="Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"menu_item[assets_attributes][3][asset]\"; filename=\"nautugly.jpg\"\r\nContent-Type: image/jpeg\r\n",
@tempfile=#<File:/var/folders/94/slp2488s6nvgg8qq0g0p5c0m0000gn/T/RackMultipart20120323-51480-1lpa754>>,
"description"=>""},...
```

and want to access a session_user_id in Asset. In the items_controller, I have added:

```
params[:item][:assets_attributes].each_with_index do |value, key|
  value.each do |y|
   y.asset.session_user_id=12
  end
```

but I get error msg:

> undefined method `asset' for "3":String

I feel like I've tried every variation. How to get this to work?

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing here but how about using values instead of each_with_index.

```
params[:item][:assets_attributes].values do |y|
  y.asset.session_user_id=12
end
```

Comment: hmm... this doesn't seem to be working. I am just trying to get the user_id asssociated with the asset. Shouldn't be this hard

Answer (score 0):

So, there are a couple of things.

First, `each_with_index` called on a `Hash` will give you the [object then the `index`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Enumerator.html#method-i-each_with_index). Since [`Hash` defines `each` as an enumerable with two variables](http://ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Hash.html#method-i-each) you will get `key` the `value`.

```
params[:item][:assets_attributes].each_with_index do |attr1, attr2|
  puts attr1 # ["3", {"asset" => "MyAsset!"}]
  puts attr2 # 0

  attr1.each do |value|
    puts value 
    # "3" on First Run
    # {"asset" => "MyAsset!"} on Second Run
  end
end
```

So if you just want to mess with the values then I suggest [natedavisolds'](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9848306/527152) approach. But that leads us to our second problem. Accessing a `Hash`; you need to do it using brackets`[]` not method calls.

All in all it should look something like this,

```
params[:item][:assets_attributes].values.each do |y|
  y[:session_user_id] = 12
end
```

Comment: thx for answer, this makes sense but it's just not working :-( I'm using paperclip. Maybe try with no asset?

Comment: I re-read your question, I thought `asset` was an embedded model. Now I realize it's actually an attribute of an `Asset`. So you would just strip [:asset] off the `Hash` index.